# Why would one NOT buy ESD-safe tools?

Tags: esd

For audio work, Arduino work and other electronics projects, why would you decide NOT to buy esd-safe screwdrivers, pliers, cutters and tweezers?

Comment: How about cost and availability in the local hardware shop?

Comment: For ESD when I do is simply touch the big iron body before touching components. And in a country like here[high humidity ]ESD won't live that long. It may be recommend to use ESD safe tools no matter where you are, strict to standard will save you from thousands of problems.

Comment: The cost benfit ratio is low in much hobby use.  However if I were to be working on High Voltages I would prefer HV rated insulated tools over a Static dissipative tool with carbon loaded part conductive covering.

Answer (score 2):

1. Few tools are available specifically as ESD-safe.

   Those that are cost more.

   They are more of a hassle to use.

   All that stuff on the tools themselves is mostly not necessary as long as you observe general ESD precautions when really needed.

Other than that I can't think of any reason you wouldn't go out and get all ESD-safe tools.

Comment: Boss, another reason is , some tools have huge mass of iron body. So ESD spreads out and discharged as son as we touch the tool. As I could not formalize it to a answer.